# How to detect brightness in live webcam using javascript

Tags: javascript, webcam, brightness

I would like to detect the brightness of my room using the webcam and save them into a database.
I thought it would be possible with javascript, 'cause there are many jQuery plugins for webcam using. I googled lot but didn't get any good idea to complete this. So any one know about this? how to do this.

best,
brigi

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can achieve that in pure javascript, but if you can grab an image then just send that to the server and use a server side script to analyse the brightness of the image and store that in the database.

On the server side you will find a lot more script to do such things, in javascript I don't know of any work done over analysing images to that extend.

This might help [Quickly get brightness / lumanacity of images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745670/quickly-get-brightness-lumanacity-of-images)

Comment: Hi gillesc, thanks for your answer. I found a jQuery plugin(http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/) to store the picture of a webcam. Now I am searching for a solution to analyse the brightness of the picture.